# Why did Black Widow give the spear to Proxima?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

After Natasha wounded Corvus Glaive in *Avengers: Infinity War*, she threw the spear to Proxima.

Was it accidental or intentional? If intentional, then for what purpose?

Comment: Her face says it's pulled away. Her wist and arm mouvement says : not enought range for that kind of throw so it's pulled. The trajectory says it's pulled but not to the carrier hand but into her leap trajectory. Even Thor Hammer doesn't have this predictive trajectory feature. The real question is what if someone grab her feet and stop her from reaching the apex of the leap and grab the spear. Does it fly to infinity ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

### It wasn't thrown...it was pulled away.

At least that's the way it appears....Proxima appears to *call* the spear to her so she can use it as a weapon.

It certainly looks, to me, as though it was *pulled* from Natasha's grasp rather than being thrown backwards.

[image]

There is a "transcript" at a [**Wikia**](http://transcripts.wikia.com/wiki/Avengers:_Infinity_War) (so not official) which would seem to confirm this that I am not alone in this impression...

> [At the same time, Captain America throws Proxima's weapon to Natasha Romanoff (Black Widow) who engages Corvus, ducking under his swing, stabbing him in the gut and executing a flying kick to knock him backwards.]
>
> [Proxima, who has rushed back to the fight, **summons her weapon back to her hand and attacks Black Widow.** Captain America leaps forward, rolls, scoops up Corvus's dropped glaive and holds her off.

Comment: Obviously pulled from her hand. The spear flies _backward_ from where she's looking, one doesn't throw like that. Also the timing is just right before she can use the spear to finish off the fallen fella.

Comment: When they get beamed back into their ship, a spear also gets yanked out of Captain America's hand.

Comment: @StephenS I think Cap had Corvious' weapon, not Proxima's spear

Comment: After this, we can also see that the spear escaped from Cap.